# Returning JSON from a PHP function

Tags: php, json

I want to transform this PHP function.. that should return JSON data.

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `' . mix_player::table() . '` a';
if (isset($_GET['cat']) || isset($_GET['order'])) 
    if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
        $query .= ' INNER JOIN `' . mix_player::table_cat_rel() . '` b '
            . "ON (a.`id` = b.`idtrack`) WHERE `idcat` = '" . $wpdb->escape($_GET['cat']) . "'";

        $random = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT `random`, `order` FROM `' . mix_player::table_categories() . "` WHERE `id` = '"
            . $wpdb->escape($_GET['cat']) . "'");

        if (!$random)
            $order = $wpdb->get_var(NULL, 1);
    }

    if (isset($_GET['order']))
        $order = $_GET['order'];

    if ($order != '') {
        if (isset($_GET['cat']))
            $query .= ' AND ';
        else
            $query .= ' WHERE ';

        $tracks = mix_player::order_list($query, $order);
    }

} else {
    $random = '0';
}

$query .= ' ORDER BY `id` ASC';

if (isset($tracks) || ($tracks = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A))) {
    // option "shuffle = true" not always working into mix. Do it our own way...
    if ($random == 1) { // shuffle tracks?
        list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
        mt_srand((float) $sec + ((float) $usec * 100000));
        $nrows = count($tracks);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $nrows; $i++) {
            $j = mt_rand(0, $nrows - 1);  // pick j at random
            $row = $tracks[$i]; // swap i, j
            $tracks[$i] = $tracks[$j];
            $tracks[$j] = $row;
        }
    }

    foreach ($tracks as $row) {


        $artist = (mix_player::entities($row['artist']));
        echo ($artist);


        $title = (mix_player::entities($row['title']));

        echo ($title);

        $url =(xspf_player::entities($row['url']));
        echo ($url);        

}
}
?>
```

---

to display like this json file :

```html
{"title":"title", "artist":"artist","media":"url media.mp3","color":"#56B0E8" },
```

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just fill an array and the `json_encode` it

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create an array and populate it with your desired values, then return it as JSON:

```
function tracks2json( $tracks )
{
    $retval = array();
    foreach( $tracks as $row )
    {
        $array = array();
        $array['artist'] = mix_player::entities($row['artist']);
        $array['title']  = mix_player::entities($row['title']);
        $array['media']  = 'url '.xspf_player::entities($row['url']);
        $array['color']  = '#56B0E8';
        $retval[]        = $array;
    }
    return json_encode( $retval );
}

if( isset($tracks) || ($tracks = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A)) )
{
    // Your MySQL routine here

    $json = tracks2json( $tracks );

}
```

Comment: Works well thank you very much
But there is a problem ,it Show  3 SLASHES .. when i use--------                          echo json_encode($json); ............ ,\"media\":\"url http:\\\/\\\/

Comment: @Paradiva if you have copied exactly my code, returning value is **already json encoded**!

Comment: Is it possible to assist in modifying myplaylist.php file to become a JSON file , such as found in jsonplaylist but dynamic --- URL mediafire.com/download/jh14xe6kr4t9he9/playlist_file.rar –

Answer (score 0):

```
echo json_encode(array("title"=>$title,"artist"=>$artist,"url"=>$url));
```

Comment: thank you .. but there is a probleme of SLASHES ((  http:\/\/  ... {\"title\":"" ))